# How do I register a user control for Event validation that is calling AJAX scripts on parent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that has a JavaScript function that is called by a custom validator in a user control within the page. The page can contain multiple instances of this control which are generated within a Repeater. Only one of the controls contains the Custom Validator.

The JavaScript function calls an HTTP handler via jQuery.ajax and then updates args.IsValid accordingly.

When the Custom Validator fires the handler is called and the relevant response returned, but the page blows up with the following error:

Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I have tried the following in the user control

```
protected override void Render( HtmlTextWriter writer )
    {
        if (!this.IsLocked)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation( this.UniqueID );
        }

        base.Render( writer );
    }
```

But this makes no difference. I know I can disable Event validation in the page (which resolves the issue), but don't really want to do this. Can anyone explain what the problem is here and how I can resolve it?

Cheers
Stewart